# Configuring nginx to return a 404 when a URL matches a pattern

Tags: nginx, webserver

I want nginx to return a 404 code when it receives a request which matches a pattern, e.g., `/test/*`. How can I configure nginx to do that?

Answer (score 131):

```
location /test/ {
  return 404;
}
```

Comment: [`return` is part of the `HttpRewriteModule`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#return). It makes its parent location always return the given status, which is exactly what the requestor wants.

Comment: If you only want it to match the exact route then you can use `location = /test/ { ... }`

Answer (score 43):

Need to add "^~" to give this match a higher priority than regex location blocks.

```
location ^~ /test/ {
  return 404;
}
```

Otherwise you will be in some tricky situation. For example, if you have another location block such as

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  ...
}
```

and someone sends a request to http://your_domain.com/test/bad.php, that regex location block will be picked by nginx to serve the request. Obviously it's not what you want. So be sure to put "^~" in that location block!

Reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Answer (score 10):

```
location ^~ /test/ {
    internal;
}
```

Comment: [`internal` (from the `HttpCore` module)](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#internal) marks the location as internal to the server. It will return 404 for external requests but can still be the target of internal redirects, rewrites, error pages, etc.