# Rewrite `example.com/foo/bar` to `foo.example.com/bar` with nginx. Redirect loop

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django app that serves some user content in iframes. To avoid session hijacking I want to serve this up from a different subdomain.

I currently have the site hosted at `subdomain.example.com` with the particular iframe content at `subdomain.example.com/foo/bar/ID`. I'm now trying to set up nginx to make that specific content accessible through `foo.example.com/bar/ID` instead.

My nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        #Served with gunicorn:
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/example/example.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;

        #This is key:
        rewrite ^/(.*?) /foo$request_uri last;

        #Served with gunicorn:
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/example/example.sock;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error in the nginx `error.log`:

> 2016/01/24 14:10:41 [error] 24286#0: *17 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/foo/bar/66", client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: foo.example.com, request: "GET /bar/66 HTTP/1.1", host: "foo.example.com"

Which makes sense; the redirect is being redirect again and again because it matches the rewrite regex.

I tried adding

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
```

to no avail.

Without the redirect it does host correctly, but I'd like to avoid having the url be `foo.example.com/foo/bar/ID`.

Is there a different way to approach this that would be better? Or a way to stop the redirects?

PS: Bonus question? Next up would be blocking subdomain.example.com/foo/bar and thus forcing access through foo.example.com/bar

EDIT: I solved the question by dropping the rewrite and take care of the subdomains in django using `django-subdomains`  (https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org)

Comment: you shoud use `break` instead of `last`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution to your bonus question (i.e. how to block /foo/bar from www.example.com):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4677893/2319697

Basically just return 404 if the pattern/location is matched